# Golang Bazel empty coverage_report.dat

Tags: go, code-coverage, bazel

I am working on a small Golang monorepo and I am using Bazel + gazelle to manage deps along with tests, builds, coverage,...

I am having an issue when it comes to coverage. I have followed a few examples but for some reason the *coverage_report.dat* file (that then will be processed by *genhtml*) is always empty.

This is the command that I am running with relative output

```
$ bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov --cache_test_results=no --test_output=all //...

INFO: Using default value for --instrumentation_filter: "^//service/hello[/:],^//service/hellotwo[/:]".
INFO: Override the above default with --instrumentation_filter
INFO: Analyzed 4 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 2 targets and 2 test targets...
INFO: From Testing //service/hello:hello_test:
==================== Test output for //service/hello:hello_test:
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
================================================================================
INFO: From Testing //service/hellotwo:hellotwo_test:
==================== Test output for //service/hellotwo:hellotwo_test:
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
================================================================================
INFO: LCOV coverage report is located at /private/var/tmp/_bazel_andrea/292e77b095155ea362773b482c2c4621/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
 and execpath is bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.217s, Critical Path: 0.09s
INFO: 3 processes: 1 internal, 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions
//service/hello:hello_test                                               PASSED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_andrea/292e77b095155ea362773b482c2c4621/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/service/hello/hello_test/coverage.dat
//service/hellotwo:hellotwo_test                                         PASSED in 0.1s
  /private/var/tmp/_bazel_andrea/292e77b095155ea362773b482c2c4621/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/testlogs/service/hellotwo/hellotwo_test/coverage.dat

Executed 2 out of 2 tests: 2 tests pass.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 3 total actions
```

The coverage is calculated but `bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat` is empty. I was wondering if anyone has had this issue before and managed to find a solution to it.

I am working on a MacBook Pro with Bazel (v4.1.0) installed via Homebrew.